# Is there a way to run MySQL queries from Windows Powershell or Command Prompt?

Tags: powershell, mysql, sql-server

I currently use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to run queries on my databases, but it's a bit clunky and I prefer to do everything through a CLI if possible. Is there a way to do this on Windows?

Comment: I am guessing you are connecting to a remote server which runs SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe if you have the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio installed, all you need to do is type the following into your command prompt:

```
sqlcmd
```

Where **sqlcmd** is the executable and the switch -S is used to connect to a specific instance instead of the default instance, like so:

```
sqlcmd -S .\sqlserver20
```

---

If it is not installed, you can download it [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver15).

Running **sqlcmd** will open the utility in interactive mode, the prompt’s drive letter will be replaced by a 1, which represents the first line where you start entering your T-SQL commands. For example:

```
USE MyFirstDB;
SELECT id, name
FROM Accounts.Account
WHERE AccountType = 'us'
AND name = 'Sam';
GO
```

After you execute your commands, the prompt will restart at line 1, allowing you to submit more queries.